# Bash to instruct parent process to exit by certain PID's kill

Tags: bash, process, process-management

How is the correct bash command/instruction to exit parent process by certain signal or PID's kill when being in child process?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then a possible solution is about using `trap` if you are using shell process or commands.

**Solution 1**

**Note:** Using `trap` it seems it's useful only when you are working with shells. For example, if you are running commands in a terminal or running shell code in a script (like `myscript.sh`) you will be able to use `trap`.

Let's go through an example:

Typing `ps -fH` in my current parent process (a `zsh` shell) I get:

```bash
%> ps -fH
#Output:
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
edgar    17932 24608  0 23:37 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
edgar    18001 17932  0 23:38 pts/2    00:00:00   ps -fH
```

Now I will run a `bash` child process and type `ps -H` again:

```bash
%> bash
(bash shell) %> ps -fH
#Output:
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
edgar    17932 24608  0 23:37 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
edgar    18012 17932  0 23:38 pts/2    00:00:00   bash
edgar    18030 18012  0 23:38 pts/2    00:00:00     ps -fH
```

As you can see the the parent process of the bash shell is `zsh` with the PID `17932`.

To get the PPID of some process you should use `ps -o ppid= $SOME_PID`. For example, if you want to get the parent process ID of the current `bash` process you should use:

```bash
(bash shell) %> ps -o ppid= 18012
#Output:
17932
```

Or what is more recommendable:

```bash
(bash shell) %> ps -o ppid= $$
#Output
17932
```

With `$$` we are getting the process id of the currently running process, in this case `bash`.

Finally if you want to kill the parent process (`zsh` in this case) you should run the following command:

```bash
(bash shell) %> trap "echo Killing parent process $(ps -o ppid= $$); kill -9 $(ps -o ppid= $$)" 0 
#Or
(bash shell) %> trap "kill -9 $(ps -o ppid= $$)" 0
```

Now when you type `exit` or press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> the parent process `zsh` will be killed too:

```bash
(bash shell) %> exit
#zsh was killed too, so the terminal will show the following output:
Warning: Program '/bin/zsh' crashed
```

To avoid the *zsh has crashed* message you can run twice the `bash` shell

**Solution 2**

Using the `strace` command should work for any process. 
Let's go through an example:

We will run a process in background and with `strace` we will attach that process to can kill the parent process of this one.
First, I will execute `bash` inside my `zsh` shell

```bash
(zsh shell) %> bash
```

Now in the `bash` shell we will run a process in background, for this example, we will use the `sleep` command and get it's PPID (parent process id).

```bash
(bash shell) %> sleep 60& #sleep 1 minute (in background)
processID=$! #with $! we get the pid of the last executed process, in this case the sleep command
parentID=$(ps -o ppid= $processID)
```

If we look at `ps -fH` output we'll have something like this:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
edgar    21593 21579  0 00:43 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
edgar    22971 21593  0 01:03 pts/1    00:00:00   bash
edgar    23011 22971  0 01:07 pts/1    00:00:00     sleep 60
edgar    23012 22971  0 01:08 pts/1    00:00:00     ps -fH
```

Now we want to kill the parent process `bash` when the `sleep 60` has finished. For that, we will use the `strace -p` command:

```bash
strace -p $processID ; kill -9 $parentID
```

> strace -p is used to attach a process using its PID.

When the process `$processID` (sleep command) is finished the kill command will run and kill the $parentID (bash shell).

**Note:** I'm not sure if it's possible with `strace` to execute a command when a signal is received. This method only will work when a process it's finished.

## Explanation of the commands above

### Use of ps

According to `ps --help`:

> -f                                  -- full listing
> --forest      -H                    -- show process hierarchy

With `ps -f` the output will show more columns than if you just use `ps`. I used `ps -f` to get the `PPID` of every process.

With `ps -H` (you can also use `ps --forest`) as the help says will show the process hierarchy i.e. that every child process of some process will be displayed in a special format. Running `ps -H` I get:

```bash
PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2872 pts/1    00:00:00 zsh
 3771 pts/1    00:00:00   bash
 7259 pts/1    00:00:00     ps
```

You can see that `ps` is a child process of `bash` and this one is a process of `zsh`.

You can also run `ps f` (that's BSD syntax) instead of `ps -H`:

```bash
%> ps f
#Output:
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2872 pts/1    Ss     0:00 /bin/zsh
 3771 pts/1    S      0:00  \_ bash
 7495 pts/1    R+     0:00      \_ ps f
```

### Use of trap

The syntax of `trap` is: `trap 'commands' SIGNAL`. That means when a process receives specific `SIGNAL` it will execute the `commands`. You can type `man trap` to get a better description:

> The condition can be EXIT, 0 (equivalent to EXIT), or a signal specified using a symbolic name, without the SIG prefix, as listed in  the  tables  of signal names in the <signal.h> header defined in the Base Definitions volume of POSIX.1‐2017. 
> ...
> XSI-conformant systems also allow numeric signal numbers for the conditions corresponding to the following signal names:
> 1     SIGHUP
> 2     SIGINT
> 3     SIGQUIT
> 6     SIGABRT
> 9     SIGKILL
> 14    SIGALRM
> 15    SIGTERM

So if you use `trap 'commands' 0` the shell will execute the `'commands'` specified in trap when you exit from the shell.

For example, the code below will execute an `echo` when the `SIGINT` is received in the bash shell:

```bash
(bash_shell) %> echo Bash PID: $$
#Output:
Bash PID: 8529
(bash_shell) %> trap 'echo Bash got SIGINT signal' 2
(bash_shell) %> kill -SIGINT 8529
#Output:
^CBash got SIGINT signal
```

Instead of `kill -SIGINT 8529` you can also press: <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in the bash shell.

**Note:** Using `trap` for some signals might not work (I've tested with SIGKILL and it didn't work).

### Use of kill

You can use `man kill` or `man 1p kill` to get more detailed description about that command.

> kill -s signal_name pid
>
> kill -l [exit_status]
>
> kill [-signal_name] pid
>
> kill [-signal_number] pid
> ...
> -s signal_name
> Specify the signal to send, using one of the symbolic names defined in the <signal.h> header. Values of signal_name shall be recognized  in
> a  case-independent  fashion,  without  the SIG prefix. In addition, the symbolic name 0 shall be recognized, representing the signal value
> zero. The corresponding signal shall be sent instead of SIGTERM.
> -signal_name 
> Equivalent to -s signal_name.
>
> -signal_number
> Specify a non-negative decimal integer, signal_number, representing the signal to be used instead of SIGTERM, as the sig  argument  in  the
> effective call to kill().  The correspondence between integer values and the sig value used is shown in the following list.The effects of specifying any signal_number other than those listed below are undefined.
> 0     0
> 1     SIGHUP
> 2     SIGINT
> 3     SIGQUIT
> 6     SIGABRT
> 9     SIGKILL
> 14    SIGALRM
> 15    SIGTERM

So the command `kill -9 8990` is the same as `kill -SIGKILL 8990`. Sending `SIGKILL` to a process will kill/finish this one.

Comment: It'd be very better if it's detailed on main part: -9 , 0 number, -fH option meaning or more else

Comment: @cantikmemekmu no problem! I'll update the answer in a few minutes.